# Prevent multiple ajax submissions on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've a WordPress blog running this jQuery code that allows users to click a bookmark link that saves the post as a bookmark. Each post shows a total bookmark counter that looks like: "Bookmarked (5)". Although this code works, it registers multiple clicks whenever someone clicks multiple times on the bookmark link and then saves the same post as multiple bookmarks. When the user tries to remove the bookmark by clicking on the bookmark link again, it registers multiple clicks again and the counter starts showing minus numbers which looks like: "Bookmarked (-5)".

I've been searching for an instruction on how to prevent this from happening so that the bookmark counter never runs minus and the user can't bookmark the same post multiple times but had no success so far.

Here is the jQuery code that I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

var added_message = upb_vars.added_message;
var delete_message = upb_vars.delete_message

$(document).on('click', '.upb_add_bookmark', function () {

    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var data = {
        action: 'bookmark_post',
        post_read: post_id
    };
    $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
        if($('.upb-bookmarks-list').length > 0 ) {
            var bookmark_data = {
                action: 'insert_bookmark',
                post_id: post_id
            };
            $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, bookmark_data, function(bookmark) {
                $(bookmark).appendTo('.upb-bookmarks-list');
                $('.no-bookmarks').fadeOut();
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.upb_del_bookmark', function () {

        var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var data = {
            action: 'del_bookmark',
            del_post_id: post_id
        };
        $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.bookmark-'+post_id).fadeOut();
            $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
        });

    return false;
});
});
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to add a `.disabled` class to your link before the `$.post()`.

```
// Before ajax...
if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
} else {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
}
// Make sure we refer to the same element
var that = this;

// On post success...
$(that).removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks, parchment, for providing this solution! This code works flawlessly with your help but I somehow don't find the current behaviour very user-friendly. Currently, after applying your solution, it allows the user to click once to add the bookmark and click again to remove it but after that, the 3rd click makes the page jump to the top which will confuse many users.

Could you please help me so that I can enable the users to add/remove the bookmark as many times as they want without making their clicks jump on the 3rd click and still be able to prevent multiple ajax posts?

Thanks!

Comment: @AvinashSingh You should probably replace the `return` there with `return false`. However, this means that there is a condition where the `.disabled` class is not removed. I think you probably need to add an `else { $(that).removeClass... }` to the `if ($(..).length > ..)` statement inside your first `$.post()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, parchment! You're a life saver!